# how to make values of a key of a dic uniqe?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dic. the `value` contains some results. I want to uniq them. (some of them are repetitive)

Example of `dic[0]`:

```
{'key': 'art director',
 'Results': [{'actor': 1},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'creative designer': 2},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'creative designer': 2},
  {'digital designer': 1},
  {'graphic designer': 1},
  {'communications consultant': 1},
  {'designer': 1},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'art director': 4}]}
```

output:

```
{'key': 'art director',
 'Results': [{'actor': 1},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'creative designer': 2},
  {'digital designer': 1},
  {'graphic designer': 1},
  {'communications consultant': 1},
  {'designer': 1},
]}
```

I wanted to use loop and use the following `if` condition:

```
if dic[i]['Results'][k]==dic[i]['Results'][j]
```

but it is not efficient at all. since there are 3 indices. any better way?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a dictionary for the value associated with `"Results"` instead of a list of single key dictionaries?

Comment: no, there is no reason I can change it.

Comment: Do you care that the order stays the same or not?

Comment: No, order doesn't mater. it would be great if I can sort them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary for your `"Results"` values rather than a list of single key dictionaries. So the following:

```
{
    'key': 'art director',
    'Results': [
        {'actor': 1},
        {'art director': 4},
        {'creative designer': 2},
        {'art director': 4},
        {'creative designer': 2},
        {'digital designer': 1},
        {'graphic designer': 1},
        {'communications consultant': 1},
        {'designer': 1},
        {'art director': 4},
        {'art director': 4}
    ]
}
```

becomes

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint({
    'key': 'art director',
    'Results': {
        'actor': 1,
        'art director': 4,
        'creative designer': 2,
        'art director': 4,
        'creative designer': 2,
        'digital designer': 1,
        'graphic designer': 1,
        'communications consultant': 1,
        'designer': 1,
        'art director': 4,
        'art director': 4
    }
})
```

Since dictionaries can only have one value per key, this will automatically handle deduplication as you build the `Results` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions.

#### Solution 1

This first one will output exactly what you pretended:

```
res = []   # represents the final results list
aux = {}   # used to check if the key is already in 'Results': []
for i in dic:
    for r in i['Results']:
        for k,v in r.items():
            if k not in aux.keys():
                aux[k] = v
                res.append({k:v})
    i['Results'] = res
print(dic)
```

#### Solution 2

This second one will transform `'Results'` value in `dic[I]` into a single dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries:

```
res = {}
for i in dic:
    for r in i['Results']:
        for k,v in r.items():
            res[k] = v
    i['Results'] = res
print(dic)
```

**Using your input as an example:**
Output:

```
[{'Results': {'actor': 1,
              'art director': 4,
              'communications consultant': 1,
              'creative designer': 2,
              'designer': 1,
              'digital designer': 1,
              'graphic designer': 1},
  'key': 'art director'}]
```

Sample dic:

```
dic = [{'key': 'art director',
 'Results': [{'actor': 1},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'creative designer': 2},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'creative designer': 2},
  {'digital designer': 1},
  {'graphic designer': 1},
  {'communications consultant': 1},
  {'designer': 1},
  {'art director': 4},
  {'art director': 4}]}]
```

Comment: error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: I added a sample of what dict looks like to me

Comment: Have you checked if `dic` looks like the sample?

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the creation of `dic`?

Comment: I made a data frame and dropped duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line, in order to take the whole list (The value of the key 'Result') and check for duplicates, then change it accordingly if it is already inside your key.

```
d['Results'] = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in d['Results']}]
```

Comment: it is `d[I]['Result] not d['Result']` loop over i.

Comment: @elham You wanted to strip the duplicates of 'Result' so I got the value of it in the dictionary, if you want to make it general then you need to loop, but I don't see where the `I` comes into play. It does work for me though!

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str